# How to get dictionary into 2-d table od objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a code like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict;
.
.
some[2] = new object[,]
{
{"key1", "value1"},
{"key2", "Value2"},
{"key3", "Value3"},
};
```

How can i insert automatically keys and values from dict into some[2]? THANKS!

Comment: It's very trivial `dict.Select(x => new[] { x.Key, x.Value }).ToArray()` if you come to SO to ask pretty trivial questions you're gonna have a bad time (insert ski instructor meme)

Comment: @Will Isn't this a Jagged array ?

Comment: @user3185569 This? You mean in the question, or in the trivial answer?  Which are both jagged arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can always loop to do that, example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "1", "A" },
    { "2", "B" },
    { "3", "C" },
    { "4", "D" }
};

var some = new string[dict.Keys.Count, 2];

int i = 0;
foreach(var item in dict)
{
    some[i, 0] = item.Key;
    some[i, 1] = item.Value;
    i++;
}
```

Result:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the whole dictionary by foreach statement:

```
foreach (var dictItem in dict)
{
    var key = dictItem.Key;
    var value = dictItem.Value;
    // your code to add them somewhere.
}
```